# Cauchy Problem for the Laplace Equation has a unique analytical solution in the neighbourhood of $0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The problem is an exercise of my pde assignment.

> Consider for $f,g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ the Cauchyproblem
> $$u_{tt}(t,x) + u_{xx}(t,x) = 0$$
> $$ u(0,x) = f(x) , u_t (0,x) = g(g)$$
> Show, that in a Neighbourhood of $0$ there exists a unique analytical solution, if f and g are analytical in a Neighbourhood of $0$.

The D'Alembert fromula gives us the solution $$u(x,y)=\dfrac{f(x+iy)+f(x-iy)}{2}-\dfrac{i}{2}\int_{x-iy}^{x+iy}g(t)~dt$$
but as $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ this is not defined.

So I considered to solve the equation by seperation of variables, which made me wonder, if this method provides all possible solutions. Or is it possible that there are solutions where $u(t,x)$ can't be sperated.

The next question would be, is the problem is well posed in $\mathcal S (\mathbb R)$ or $H^k(\mathbb R)$.